# Tracks for "The Hives" are not streaming via the api

Tags: soundcloud

Tracks for "The Hives" claims to be streamable, but are returning 404s.

Here's the JSON response for Civilization's Dying id 3644317 (http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/3644317.json?client_id=):

```
{
    "kind": "track",
    "id": 3644317,
    …
    "sharing": "public",
    "streamable": true,
    "embeddable_by": "all",
    "downloadable": false,
    "title": "Civilization's Dying",
    …
    "stream_url": "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/3644317/stream"    
}
```

the streamable is true and it gives a stream_url, when trying to access it with my client_id (like I've done with other tracks) it returns 404.

Edit: Sharing is public. Added the info back to the payload and a link to the api page with the full response for reference.

Answer (score 6):

There's currently a bug affecting some artists whose tracks are not actually streamable any more, but the API response not showing that fact. This should be fixed very shortly.

Comment: It's still a problem for the track mentioned. May I ask when "shortly" is?

Comment: Also looking forward to an update on this issues as it tends to confuse our users. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @zerodot yep, it's coming. Promise!

Comment: So maybe im not crazy :)

I'm having the same bizarre problem, some user's tracks will simply not play, giving me network errors, 404. But others user's play just fine and I have been unable to find the cause..

I hope the fix is made available soon, almost all of the tracks in my feed cannot be played and it is a poor user experience.

Comment: @TheoMavrakis just to be clear, these tracks will remain unplayable after the fix. The bug here is just that we're not correctly showing that the tracks aren't playable. The artists have elected to make those tracks non-streamable via the API.

Comment: I am still getting the same error with many tracks. Has this issue still not been fixed?

Comment: @Feargal: which track is showing `streamable: true`, with a `stream_url` which doesn't work?

Comment: @nickf this one does: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/124483247.json?client_id=9d5bbaf9df494a4c23475d9fde1f69b4

Comment: @nickf this is still happening on a lot of other tracks. Here is one for example: http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/99350098/stream

Comment: @nickf on this one too: https://soundcloud.com/octobersveryown/drake-days-in-the-east

Comment: @nickf is there a public way to track this bug? Kind of a major usability issue in consumer apps to present SoundCloud songs which are unplayable...

Comment: @nickf still an issue Oct 2014. Any progress?

Comment: Still facing this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this song has "sharing" set to "public" in the returned track get request. If not, you will need to authenticate with Soundcloud.

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#authentication

Comment: Sharing is public. It still is. See: http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/3644317.json?client_id=<your_client_id>

Comment: Yeah, I am having the same issue where soundcloud is returning a 404 for a bunch of songs even though the stream_url is set, its public, and streamable is true. I am just handling the error and trying to find the next track that works.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue as well when I tried to stream Lorde's (Royals) tracks. (Soundcloud userid: 27622444)

After examining the track properties returned from the API I noticed that the `streamable` property had been set to `false`

**API return data:**

```
(...)
sharing: "public"
state: "finished"
streamable: false
tag_list: ""
title: "Swingin' Party"
(...)
```

Hope that helps!

Cheers,
T

Comment: Oops, little bit to fast. Of course my answer is not related to any bug, but still - when a track will not play, check for the streamable property.