# 401 Error on Stream even though API says share is public and accepted

Tags: stream, soundcloud

So I have been chatting with my developer and we have noticed a problem with the API. Check out this song:

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/61858057?client_id=[MYCLIENTID]

My developer said to say that:

true is on.
Share is public.
Stream is accepted.

But you can't actually access the stream in our player as the stream returns a 401 error instead.

Can anyone offer any insight into why or what may be happening here so I can pass that info back to my developer?

Hoping someone can help.
Thanks

Comment: Hey Chris, I'm not sure I understand your problem, trying to `GET` the sound above works fine for me – http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/61858057?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID

Comment: when you say “Stream”, what you refer to?

Answer (score 0):

This is the same issue as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15247013/9021). Basically, this artist has disabled streaming of their tracks via the API, but the track representation is still showing that it's playable when it's not.

There's a fix due to go out soon -- but be aware that this track will still remain unplayable, the fix will merely show this state correctly.